# error : JSR/RET are not supported with computeFrames option

Tags: android

i am facing this error **Execution failed for task app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.JSR/RET are not supported with computeFrames option**

**my main activity :**

```
    package piestudio.opinion;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override


    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();


            if (id == R.id.toi) {

                Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment);
                ft.commit();


                return true;

            } else if (id == R.id.thehindu) {

            } else if (id == R.id.support) {


            }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }


    }
```

**i have created another Fragment name FragmentOne**

```
    package piestudio.opinion;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

/**
 * Created by jene on 7/4/2016.
 */
public class FragmentOne extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);



        }
    }
```

**as i am using Navigation Drawer so here is my contentMain**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="piestudio.opinion.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/content_frame"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment1 (the xml file of FragmentOne)**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="one" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Disable Instant run from settings

Answer (score 6):

Try turning off the instant run.

1. Open the Settings or Preferences dialog:

   - On Windows or Linux, select File > Settings from the main menu.
   - On Mac OSX, select Android Studio > Preferences from the main menu.
2. Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run

Comment: This is rather a (bad) workaround but not a real solution. It does not explain, why this happens and how to resolve this issue while keeping the Instant Run-feature intact.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement @Kanika answer, there is a issue about that and it is going to be fixed on Android Studio 2.3

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220019

Answer (score 0):

This issue had been fix in android gradle plugin 2.3 .

Change-Id: I28677d1516033503cede27013307531a8ccd1ee1
will be fixed in 2.3 train.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220019